# FlowLayout not flowing with JScrollPane around it

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jscrollpane, flowlayout

I have a bunch of buttons on a JPanel using a FlowLayout.  It looks really nice.  When the buttons reach the right side of the panel they start out on a new row creating a nice 2-dimensional grid.

Here is the code:

```
    Container cp = getContentPane();
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        panel.add(new JButton("Button " + i));
    cp.add(panel);
```

However, the minute I put the panel in a scroll pane with only vertical scrolling:

```
    Container cp = getContentPane();
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        panel.add(new JButton("Button " + i));
    JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane(
            panel,
            ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED,
            ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
    cp.add(pane);
```

the buttons are only shown in one row (and I can't even see the ones off to the right).  I still want them to wrap.  What is going on here?  By the way, I need to show only the vertical scroll bar and no horizontal scroll bar.  I want the buttons to wrap to a new row when they reach the right end.

Comment: Why don't you read the answers in your last question?

Comment: I did read the answers in my last question (in fact, I commented on a couple of them).  I realized I was asking the wrong question.  I do want a FlowLayout.  I'm just confused as to why adding the JScrollPane causes the buttons not to wrap onto new lines when they reach the right-hand side.

Comment: If you say so, but I gave you the answer over 2 hours ago.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out my answer here: [How can I let JToolBars wrap to the next line (FlowLayout) without them being hidden ty the JPanel below them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3679886/how-can-i-let-jtoolbars-wrap-to-the-next-line-flowlayout-without-them-being-hid)

There is a custom Flow Layout that I have used in this exact situation.  Just plug it in and it wraps even in a scroll pane.